# placing labels dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

In my .mxml file, I am populating two side by side Labels with text data from a database.

Like this:

```
    <s:Label x="10" y="37.5" width="100%" text="{data.city}"/>
    <s:Label x="86" y="36.75" width="100%" text="{data.state}"/>
```

Sometimes, I will get a particularly long piece of text data and this will cause the 2 labels to overlap each other and become totally unreadable.

I think this is happening because I have the x and y set.  Is there a way to make this more dynamic?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to know that layout that is being applied to these labels. Since you are using X/Y it looks like `BasicLayout` (the default). If you are using `HorizontalLayout` setting X/Y has no effect...

Comment: Sorry, it is basicLayout

Comment: set width to a predefined width other then a percent. In your case the first label should have a width of no greater then 76

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend exploring different Flex layout containers.

### HGroup

```
<s:HGroup>
    <s:Label text="{data.city}"/>
    <s:Label text="{data.state}"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

This provides the kind of layout it sounds like you're looking for from your example. However, you may also want to look at a few other containers Flex offers.

### Form

Flex forms align data in ways that are often useful for creating, well, forms. You may want to consider this for your UI, especially if you're allowing a user to give input that persists back to your DB.

```
<s:Form>
    <s:FormItem label="City:">
        <s:Label text="{data.city}"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem label="State:">
        <s:Label text="{data.state}"/>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
```

Comment: wouldnt I run into the same issue though if I had a really long city name?  thanks

Comment: @999cm999 The containers will dynamically change size as their content changes. When the content changes, the ui components sizes/properties are marked invalid. Because of this, when they are redrawn their sizes will be recalculated.

Answer (score 1):

Try set X of second label with the width of the first label + space + x first label.

So: first label width + space + x of first label

Comment: first label width + space + x of first label :)

Comment: Can't +1 you until you fix your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do a couple of things:

If you have a function that gets called to set the values of each label, reposition the labels based on the contents in that function.

If the values for the labels are bound to data so that you don't necessarily get notified when the data is refreshed, then it's time to override the `updateDisplayList()` method of UIComponent, and have it reposition your labels there.

There is a lot of efficiency that can be gained (which will improve your performance) by understanding and using the life-cycle of a UIComponent.  There's lots of good info on the subject out there if you just google "Flex component lifecycle"

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

if you have to display your labels in a limited width, then you can use maxWidth property of labels, this will display your text in label, and if text is long then it will show some text and remaining in ... format.

```
<s:Label text="{data.city}" maxWidth="150"/>
```